# Change keyboard input text in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to change keyboard input ,

Example :

**When user press a , it will be show c**

I tried to use `TextWatcher` and it hang because after calling `setText` , it will be arrive again TextWatcher event. So, it will deadlock and not working.

`setOnKeyListener` is not working also. `onKey` event arrive when Enter. Not arriving when I press a or b.

It is possible to change text input key in EditText Android ?

Update: setOnKeyListener

```
final EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View arg0, int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("onKey", "Arrive Keypress");
                if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    return true;

                 if (event != null&& (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                     applySearch();
                     return true;
                 }

                return false;
            } 


        });
```

Comment: `setOnKeyListener` should work. Please should your code.

Comment: You are explicitly checking for keycode being ENTER - of course it doesn't work for other keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TextWatcher`, but use it smart. When you call `setText` create `boolean flag == true` , and check every time this `flag` in `onTextChanged`. Hope its help.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

EditText et;
boolean flag;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
    et.addTextChangedListener(this);

}


@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if(flag)
    {
        flag = false;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //do same staff
        flag = true;
        et.setText("new text");
    }
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its feasible,I use sling keyboard(you could find this app on Google Play).You could choose it as default under keyboard setting in your phone.

Rgds,

Ambar

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about.  He wants to change input on the fly programmatically regardless of the keyboard being used.